# jQuery fadeout on scroll conflict

Tags: jquery, debugging, scroll

I'm new to jQuery and so am learning as I go on.

On a website that I am creating there are 2 functions that seem to be conflicting: the 1st one is so that the title of the website fades out when the user starts to scroll and the 2nd one is for smooth scrolling between anchors on the page.
The 2nd script makes the fade out script run straight away even without the user scrolling.

Here is a fiddle that shows the idea : http://jsfiddle.net/Mvf67/284/

And here is the code:

```
// fade out
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $(".title").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});

// smooth scroll
$(document).ready(function () {
    function filterPath(string) {
        return string.replace(/^\//, '')
        .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '')
        .replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
    var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

    $('a[href*=#]').each(function () {
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if (locationPath == thisPath && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname) && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
            var $target = $(this.hash),
            target = this.hash;
            if (target) {
                 var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                 $(this).click(function (event) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                     $(scrollElem).animate({
                         scrollTop: targetOffset
                     }, 1500, function () {
                         location.hash = target;
                     });
                 });
            }
       }
  });

  function scrollableElement(els) {
      for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i < argLength; i++) {
          var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
          if ($scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0) {
              return el;
          } else {
              $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
              var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0;
              $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
              if (isScrollable) {
                  return el;
              }
          }
      }
      return [];
   }

});
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT: The fiddle link has been repaired*

Comment: Your fiddle is broken!

Comment: Click update/save button after you write your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

keep only one `document.ready` function instead of two